# Possibility of predicting random number with PHP rand()

Tags: php, random, security, password-protection

This is a long question to read so **Question in short** is, is it secure to depend on PHP's `rand` function for generating first time password?

In my free time, I was just thinking of a logic to make very difficult custom password generator (only digits), a feature that I might need in my next project.

First thing that come in mind is PHP's `rand()` method. I tried few test around `rand` method to test its random behaviour. As general, it first come to mind that generating more than one random number and doing some operation on that will make random number more difficult to guess. I was surprised to see that average of random numbers is very near to its half using following program:

```
$minAvg=$maxAvg=50;
for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++){
    //Random average
    $sum=0;
    for($j=0;$j<1000;$j++){
        $sum=$sum+rand(1,100);
    }
    $avg=$sum/1000;
    ///

    if($avg<$minAvg){
        $minAvg=$avg;
    }
    if($avg>$maxAvg){
        $maxAvg=$avg;
    }
    if($i%100==0)
    {
        echo "at i=$i, Min Avg = $minAvg and Max Avg = $maxAvg <br/>";
    }
}
```

One output of above code was:

```
at i=100, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.003
at i=200, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.003
at i=300, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.003
at i=400, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.003
at i=500, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.192
at i=600, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.192
at i=700, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.192
at i=800, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.192
at i=900, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.204
at i=1000, Min Avg = 47.174 and Max Avg = 53.204
```

I run above code at least 50 times but even after 1000 iteration, average always remain between 47.xx to 53.xx (for random numbers between 1 & 100)

Although this result doesn't tells a lot as generally average of few numbers must come near middle but I didn't expected same behaviour for random numbers. **I feel it show PHP's rand() use some fixed algorithm which generate numbers in a given pattern. As far as I understand, this is only justified reason for average to remain near middle.**

Till now I was using random numbers frequently to generate first time password (which was forcefully changed during first login). However now I'm little worried if it is safe to use random numbers for generating first time passwords of sites which involve financial transaction and sensitive info like credit card numbers (although encrypted). Is there any possibility for hackers (not amateur but professional hackers) to break such passwords with easy? Most important, is there any algorithm to detect (or at least estimate) next random number.

**Edit**
Well to make it more sensible, user will be registered offline for example like opening bank account and `printed first time password` will be sent through Post, not by email. So password must remain under 10 characters which rules out any encryption.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look on the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c) of the `rand()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rand()` is not a cryptographic-strength RNG, but it does not matter here.

All you need from a random password is that it should be unpredictable enough that random guessing is not feasible. This property has much more to do with the length and allowed character pool of the password than it has to do with `rand()`.

Moreover, the best line of defense against brute forcing is *introducing a deliberate delay between login attempts*. If you do this and have "reasonably random" passwords there is absolutely no way you are going to get brute forced.

And finally, under the hood `rand()` is implemented using a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). Unless the server is going to spend most of its time generating passwords (highly doubtful) you can get "better" randomness by switching to `mt_rand()`, which is an implementation of [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) (it's still not crypto-strength).

Comment: The advantage of `mt_rand` is pretty negligible in this case, since the seeding utterly sucks either way.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Although I agree that it should not matter what RNG is used for this as long as it's not totally broken, I don't see how you can so casually *quantify* the advantage (assuming one exists) or which part of the answer merits a downvote. Could you offer some concrete feedback?

Comment: It seeds with the time and the process id. At *best* this is a 32 bit value. But since both are rather predictable, I'd put the actual entropy at below half of that. The quality of the PRNG matters far less than the quality of the seed in such scenarios. The way `rand` and `mt_rand` are seeded is essentially identical, so the advantage of `mt_rand` is negligible. If people seeded their non crypto PRNGs decently I'd complain far less, but they don't.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: If you don't counter brute force by introducing delays (and possibly lockouts) even godlike crypto won't help you after the user changes their password to "123456" -- so you **must** do this if you are serious about security. And if you do it, then any non-sucky crypto will suffice for temporary passwords. So while I fully agree with using strong crypto (because why not?), in the context of this question I believe that focusing on the crypto is losing the forest for the trees.

Comment: I agree on `brute force` point, we are going to use policy that if wrong password entered 3 times, account will be temporarily suspended for further login. For next login, user will have to enter 'One time password' (+ password) sent to his/her registered mobile. If mobile number is not registered for user, new password will be sent through post. It might be frustrating experience for users who do not have registered mobile but better then loosing some money due to unauthorized access. So its still my accepted answer although we are discussing the feasibility to create custom random algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

PHP [uniqid](https://www.php.net/uniqid) is what you are looking for. Usage Example:

```
$code = uniqid(rand(), true);
```

Be aware there is a more secure function [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) but it's available only on PHP>5.3

Comment: the goal of `uniqid` is to be unique, not to be secure/unpredictable.

Comment: How could you predict this value `uniqid(rand(), true);` from outside ?

Answer (score 1):

One relatively simple way to generate secure random numbers in php is `mcrypt_create_iv` with `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` as `$source`. i.e. `mcrypt_create_iv(size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)`. Then transform the resulting random bytes into whatever form you need.

Comment: This is total overkill for the occasion though.

Comment: @Jon This is a security related use, so use a crypto PRNG. Personally I use them for *everything*.

Answer (score 0):

**Before you downvote read the question, and then read the following as a solution to the problem, thanks.**

You are prolly doing something a lot more insecure than password predictability, like sending the "first time" password using emails.

Wether you stick with generating passwords, or use the alternative method of sending a first time auto-login URL (what I would recommend) you still need to prevent predictability of passwords or secret keys for the URL.

You need have very long secret salt like this (keyboard random is fine):
`$salt="aslkfhaqoiey19836y9qasdhkasjdhbknmxcbnzmbAkua089610"`.

Then create first-time passwords or keys for your URL using rand() but in combination with md5 and that very long salt. Since the salt is secret, nobody can predict what md5 will result into.

`$randomPassword=base64_encode(md5(rand().rand().$salt, true));`

Comment: Wont this be a bit too long for a password? You do know, that lots of people type the possword on their own.

Comment: No, MD5 is fixed length, 32 characters in hex (base16 notation) or less in base64. Of course you can always substring it, and send only 6 chars.

Comment: Now tell me, how many times I will need to rewrite a 16 character long base64 coded password before I get it right?

Comment: This answer solves the predictability problem of the password. Why the downvote?

Comment: Now write this password right in the first time: `Jrh6TtWkzDa+/Y0pVmxNNA==` Thats what your script generates.

Comment: So clean it...and keep only the first 5 letters. Big deal?

Comment: Well thanks for the answer (I didn't down voted) but it will not fit for the problem. Check edit in question at the end.

Comment: @KapilSharma Seriously, you want me to show you how to use `substr` or `preg_replace`?

Comment: I know that but I need digit only password, mentioned in question as password can be used from mobiles too, where characters and special symbols can't be entered.

Comment: So instead of base 64, use base 10. Again, what's the big deal? The problem you presented is about the possibility of predicting the password, not how to do base transformations, substr, preg_replace and what not.

Comment: I appreciate your input Tiberiu. We will decide best algorithm/method in architect's meeting and I'll give a thought to your solution too. Not sure about your solution but +1 for your rep loss here and your helpful nature.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `rand().rand()` being unique. Another downside is the long-term secret.

Comment: Generally passwords don't have to be unique. Regardless, since they are saved as is, in case of a conflict the process can be repeated... The secret can be disposed of, ~weekly (a new keyboard random from time to time).